# Xcode sdk pass param to NSURLRequest

Tags: iphone, xcode

For my iphone application I need to make a request to the server with a parameter in the url.
I am new to dev ios applications and I can't figure it out how to pass a value I set into the url.

I have tried something like this but it says "too many arguments" for the URLWITHString.
How do I write down this in the right way?

```
  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://test.localhost/api/request.php?url=%@", passedValue] cachePolicy: NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:15.0];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Thanks in advance,
Nick

Comment: `NSString *urlstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://test.localhost/api/request.php?url=%@", passedValue];`
`NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlstring cachePolicy: NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:15.0];`

Comment: @hpiOSCoder - this is not going to work, you need to use stringWithFormat method.

Comment: before u could comment I'v changed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://test.localhost/api/request.php?url=%@", passedValue]; 
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] cachePolicy: NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:15.0];
```

EDIT -

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://test.localhost/api/request.php?url=%@", passedValue]] cachePolicy: NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:15.0];
```

Comment: Thanks, I see I had to combine them later together right? regards, nick

Comment: @user968898 - if you want to combine statements then also you can. or you can break them in 2.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
NSString *tempURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://test.localhost/api/request.php?url=%@", passedValue]; 
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:tempURL] cachePolicy: NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:15.0];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to give a NSString object to your urlwithstring param

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://test.localhost/api/request.php?url=%@", passedValue]] cachePolicy: NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:15.0];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```